# a cleaner way to add tabs/tab content dynamically with bootstrap/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently adding tabs dynamically like so:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    var hotel = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (hotel) {
        $('.nav-tabs').append('<li class="hotel"><a href="#hotel" data-toggle="tab">Hotel</a></li>');
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane hotel" id="hotel"><div>lol</div></div>');
    } else {
        $('.hotel').remove();
    }
});
```

But I think that is really messy in that there is a lot of html that is being generated in my JS. These tabs will essentially be holding form inputs, so I can see this javascript getting messy very quickly.

Am I doing this right or is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding the hotel tab to markup, but hiding it by default? Add `display: none;` to your `.hotel` css class and the javasript will be something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
    var hotel = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('.hotel').toggle(hotel);
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just toyed with hide/show (didn't think about toggle) and that seems to work. But really it's only hiding the elements, not removing them completely, which would be a dangerous thing if submitting a form (i.e. the user decided to opt-out of getting a hotel after they filled in some data, and it got submitted anyway)

Comment: @a7omiton, yes. I'd go with cheking the value of the checkbox on the server side.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you'd be checking them anyway. Thanks for the conversation